# Serialize an Int array c++ for an mysql column

Tags: c++, mysql

I have an array of 128 ints. Which I want as a column in my mysql table. (or if someone has a better Idea that is welcome)

Basically I don't know 2 things:

1) What is the syntax for this process in C++ i.e serializing the data and inserting it into the table.

```
  int x = 1;
  int myarray[128];
  serialize(myarray);//?
  mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO db VALUES('"x"', myarray)"); 
  //int myarray[128]; also dont  know the syntax for the int value insertion.
```

2) What is the syntax for the table creation process with this serialized data i.e

```
   mysql_query(con, "CREATE TABLE table(Id INT not null, (serialized int array[128]))");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what the column type would be either

Comment: _'what the column type would be'_ Some raw data _blob_ may be. I'm not that experienced with MySQL, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the [MySql INSERT INTO syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) is:

```
INSERT INTO db
("X")
VALUES ((1), (2), (3));
```

You don't want to serialize an array for this.  You want the textual representation of each value in the array.

I suggest using `std::ostringstream` and a `for` loop to build a string containing the textual representations of the array contents.

You could do as I did and search the web for examples of the correct syntax:
[Wikipedia - SQL Syntax for INSERT into, including multiple rows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29)

**Edit 1:**
Also search the web for "MySql Load File":
[Google results of "MySql load file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20load%20data&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)

Comment: I actually do not want a text value... why would I?
I don't need the each value by themselves I need the array as a whole.
And since I don't want to create a table with 129 columns I would need to serialize the data lets say

int ar[128] to char charar[512]
Then memcpy. That was my idea wondering if there is something better then that

Comment: Look at the `load file` statement.  Also review the `MySql Connector C++` interface to see if there is a method to load multiple rows.